# c++ thread assignment throwing SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm sure I'm just plain doing something stupid, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.  I am trying to write a class that will become the framework for modules in our app.  Each module will have a message queue and go off and process those messages in it's own thread.  problem is when I call run() the thread creation and assignment to the member variable causes a SIGSEGV.  How would I correctly assign the new thread to a member variable of the class?

EDIT:  new test case posted

```
class TestModule
{
public:
    TestModule(){}
    virtual ~TestModule(){}

    void run()
    {
        // create the thread
        thrd = std::move(std::thread(&TestModule::_run, this));
    }

protected:
    std::thread thrd;                       // the running thread

private:
    void _run()
    {
        while (!true) {
            sleep(5);   // pretend to do stuff
        }
    }
};

class SimpleApp : public TestModule
{
public:
    ~SimpleApp() {}
};

int main() {
    SimpleApp app;
    app.run();

    int ctr=0;
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all ‘bNeedsToQuit‘ used from multiple threads but is not protected by a mutex or atomic so you already have undefined behaviour (if hadn't forgotten to set to true somewhere). Also did you enable threading when compiling (-pthreads iirc)? You also never join your thread. You are also moving from a temporary.

Comment: I have stripped out almost all the synchronization in order to provide as concise a sample as possible.  I have it all in a single file now and it still is crashing with SIGSEGV...how do I post the new code?  Should I just go edit my original post with the new code?

Comment: This version also [runs forever without error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6546c4ce2ee24d03). What command line are you using to compile? Platform, compiler, versions? (Unrelated, you don't need the `std::move` in the assignment to `thrd`. You're assigning a temporary, so it's already an rvalue.)

Comment: [Do you get output from this program, or does it crash before producing any?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8f507873d5568a0)

Comment: ok, not sure how to mark this as resolved.  after moving all the code into a simple test.cpp file, I noted as did Casey, that it works just fine, so I started unwinding the production code one step at a time.  It appears that a library I was linking to (utility library that we use with all kinds of database functions and string functions, etc) was built single threaded.  Once I rebuilt that library with -pthread, and re-linked to this app, the crash stopped happening.  What's the best way to post that as an answer

Comment: Simply post an answer stating that and mark it as accepted. Since it was your own solution then you can answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after moving all the code into a simple test.cpp file, I noted as did Casey, that it works just fine without seg faulting.

so I started unwinding the production code one piece at a time. It appears that a third library I was linking to (utility library that we use with all kinds of database functions and string functions, etc) was built single threaded. Once I rebuilt that library with -pthread, and re-linked to this app, the crash stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` will call `std::terminate` if you do not `join()` it.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999432/stdthread-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception-dont-want-to-joi) for more info.
Therefore,

```
void TestModule::run()
{
    // what do we need to do before moving on?
    bNeedsToQuit = false;

    // create the thread
    thrd = std::move(std::thread(&TestModule::_run, this));
    thrd.join();
}
```

Comment: but if I join the thread in run() then the main app will sit at line 2 of main() because the main thread is waiting for the second thread to complete.  this would subsequently prevent the main app from posting messages to the 2nd thread which should continue running for the life of the app.

Comment: You are sort-of correct. The destructor of `std::thread` will call `std::terminate` if the thread is joinable, which never happens in this program since it runs forever. At some point it will be necessary to throw something like `if (thrd.joinable) thrd.join();` in the `TestModule` destructor. But that is not the current problem with the program.

Comment: You've asked us why you get `SIGSEGV` and I've told you why. You should give us more details on what you are expecting in order to answer you.

Comment: The thread (`thrd`) will not be destroyed until the `app` in `main` is destroyed, which won't happen until `main` returns.

Comment: Please note that terminate != SIGSEGV. The OP program is actually crashing before the problem you are highlighting.

Comment: Once the original problem is fixed though, then the solution to the not joining problem would be to put `thrd.join()` in `~TestModule()`. That way the thread will join just before `main` exits.

Comment: I couldn't find any points which could issue a SIGSEGV, so I had guessed he meant that. Signals and exceptions are different things, of course.

Comment: The program was actually seg faulting.  please note my comment above as to what I did to solve it